# Azure Policy - Enforce no service to use AppGateway Subnet

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-policy

Is there a way via Azure Policy to enforce no services can be provisioned on a subnet thats dedicated to AppGateway subnet. This is similar to AzureBastion subnet where you cannot provision any other services in AzureBastion subnet. As this isn't available by default, i would like to see if it can be implemented via Azure Policy. I have a policy that enforces AppGateway to be deployable only in a subnet , but it doesnt enforce other services to not use the same subnet.

```
"policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/gatewayIPConfigurations[*].subnet.id",
                        "notContains": "AppGatewaySubnet"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "Deny"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following policy uses the `like` operator to match any resource that is being deployed into the specific subnet dedicated to the Application Gateway. The `notLike` operator is then used to match any resource type that is not an Application Gateway. If a resource matches these conditions, the `deny` effect takes place, blocking the deployment of that resource.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/subnetId",
          "like": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{vNetName}/subnets/AppGatewaySubnet"
        },
        {
          "field": "type",
          "notLike": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/*"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: I get an error as Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/subnetId isnt an alias under provider 'Microsoft.Network' and resource type 'virtualNetworks/subnets',